# How to retrieve variables from view file to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have some variable in view file ,those variable i want use in my controller ,is it possible to fetch variables from `view/html_t1/test.php` to
`controller.php` ?
Please help me ,if any one knows.
Thanks

Comment: did you try ajax? At onload event, you can call ajax and send in POST your needed variables

Comment: NO ,because in my view/html_t1/test.php is only for variable ,i can not write another code .Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is too broad for SO, and it is likely to be closed unless you edit it and narrow it down to a specific problem you are having.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The only way to it is using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript (ajax) to connect the view with the controllers. For example if you want to pass the variable '**variable1**' with the value 999 you can pass that variable by GET

```
<script>
function sendVariables() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "index.php/Controller?variable1=999", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And in the controller you can get the value:

```
$variable1 = $this->input->get('variable1'); //value 999
```

Documentation of ajax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX